# Correct OSMnx Custom Filter Syntax

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx, overpass-api

I have just updated to a newer version of OSMnx (0.16) and one of my scripts no longer works.

```
  G = ox.graph_from_point(yx, 
                    dist = 5000,
                    dist_type = 'bbox', 
                    infrastructure = 'way["railway"]',
                    network_type = 'none',
                    custom_filter = '["service"!~"yard|siding"]["railway"~"%s"],
                    truncate_by_edge = True,
                    retain_all = True
                     )
```

This was designed to pull all subways but exclude all sidings. However, the `infrastructure` parameter is no longer available in the latest version.

Apparently, I need to incorporate the `infrastructure` information within the custom query, however, I am not sure how to do so. I am not sure what the correct syntax of a customer filter ought to be.

Any ideas would be a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

Read through the OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_point) and usage [examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples). They explain how to use the custom filter. And read through the Overpass query language [wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL), which explains the syntax itself in great detail.

```py
import osmnx as ox
point = 40.750972, -73.992778
G = ox.graph_from_point(point,
                        custom_filter = '["railway"~"subway"]["service"!~"yard|siding"]',
                        truncate_by_edge = True,
                        retain_all = True)
len(G) #79
```